# What to do if Cryptographic provider version in dll is different from the guid recorded in system catalog?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dll, azure-keyvault, connector

I am attempting to establish EKM with AKV, thus far I have followed the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/setup-steps-for-extensible-key-management-using-the-azure-key-vault?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=portal) but I am now faced with an error at part 5 which states

> Cryptographic provider version '01.00.0004.00' in dll is different
> from the guid recorded in system catalog for provider with id 65536.

does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/899558/what-to-do-if-cryptographic-provider-version-in-dl.html)

Answer (score 0):

- According to this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-cryptographic-provider-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), you must use the ALTER CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROVIDER command if the provider modifies the.dll file that is needed to perform Extensible Key Management in SQL Server.
- Operations like disabling the provider ,checking the DLL signature and confirming that the GUID in the .dll file matches the one listed in the catalogue and updating the catalog's DLL version are carried out by SQL Server when the path to the.dll file is modified using the ALTER CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROVIDER statement
- Any efforts on new connections to use an EKM provider with encryption statements will fail if it is set to DISABLE. All sessions utilising a provider must be ended in order to disable it.